# substring like mysql in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am new to the sql server. I need the substring_index like mysql. I am using substring, partindex for sqlserver. I am using the following comment in sql server:

```
select substring('13.1039901,80.1294101',PATINDEX('%13.1039901,80.1294101%',','),1);
```

Result:

```
It gives empty result
```

But in mysql:

```
select substring_index('13.1039901,80.1294101',',',1) ;
```

Result:

```
13.1039901
```

Note:
I don’t know the substring count for some cases. Anyone please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use this pattern in PATINDEX it should return 1 since the pattern matches your entire string.
So if you replace PATINDEX by the result your query looks like `SUBSTRING('13.1039901,80.1294101', 1, 1)`.

Now SUBSTRING works like this:
`SUBSTRING ( expression ,start , length )`.

That means the start index for the characters you want to return is 1 (see the first paragraph) and the length of the string you want to return is 1 as well.
I didn't test this myself but I would expect that your expression returns the character **1** as in **1**3.1039901,80.1294101.

To get the result you seem to be looking for you could use
`SELECT SUBSTRING('13.1039901,80.1294101', 1, CHARINDEX(',', '13.1039901,80.1294101') - 1)`
which should give you everything before the comma as a result.

This way `start` is the beginning of your string and `length` is the position of the comma so the string is cut off there.

Comment: thank you for your immediate reply. It is very useful to me.